# Css flex adjust alignments for both mobile and desktop version

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

Blue is desktop version, red is mobile version.

There are 3 texts, and each text container should be not long as the parent but as the text width (and a padding).

The vertical and horizontal alignment is different for desktop and mobile.

For desktop the 3 texts should be left aligned and vertical center aligned.
For mobile they should be horizontally centered but not vertically.

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-36i3y?file=/src/App.js) (I'm using tailwind):

```
<div className={`w-full h-full ${isMobile ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-blue-400"}`}>
  <div
    className={`fixed flex flex-col ${
      isMobile ? "items-center" : "justify-center ml-3"
    } border-2 border-pink-400`}
    style={{ top: isMobile ? "5%" : "" }}
  >
    <div className="bg-white p-1 text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">A title</div>
    <div className="bg-white p-1 text-lg mb-4">Here something else</div>
    <div className="bg-white p-1 text-sm">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the alignments are not correct and on desktop version, text containers are larger than the text.

I'm not sure about `40% from top` but the result should be similar to the draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done through `@media` query to know what screen is used and then just apply styles:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:415px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: orange;
  }

}
@media screen and (min-width:416px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: baseline;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div className="one">A title</div>
    <div className="two">Here something else</div>
    <div className="three">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not want I want

Comment: @whitecircle I thought that for desktop the 3 texts should be left aligned and vertical center aligned, and for mobile they should be horizontally centered but not vertically.